# Using MAX in WHERE Clause with < -Operator

Tags: sql-server

I want to select the entries in a table when the registration adress is equal to one (of more than one) delivery adresses AND this adress is the adress where the customer sent all his orders to this adress, since the adress was created.
Date 1 = Date of first order to specific adress, Date 2 = Last/Newest Order to specific adress.To make iot easier to understand... I´ve got this (Table1):

The task:

```
|cID ||company|Street  |Code|del     |Street2 |Cod2|Date 1    |Date 2    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1   ||Ex1    |ABC Rd.1|4025|Ex1     |DEL St.1|0212|01.01.2015|06.03.2015|
|1   ||Ex1    |ABC Rd.1|4025|Ex1     |REF Wy.1|9875|26.02.2015|16.05.2015|
|1   ||Ex1    |ABC Rd.1|4025|Ex1     |ABC Rd.1|4025|13.06.2015|08.08.2015|
|2   ||Ex2    |HIO Wy.1|9999|Ex2     |DEL St.1|0212|13.03.2015|09.07.2015|
|2   ||Ex2    |HIO Wy.1|9999|Ex2     |REG St.1|6754|21.02.2015|16.05.2015|
|2   ||Ex2    |HIO Wy.1|9999|Ex2     |BLA Rd.5|0897|01.03.2015|06.12.2015|
|2   ||Ex2    |HIO Wy.1|9999|Ex2     |HIO Wy.1|9999|09.10.2015|26.11.2015|
|3   ||Ex3    |REG St.1|1114|Ex3     |DEL St.9|0212|13.01.2015|09.02.2015|
|3   ||Ex3    |REG St.1|1114|Ex3     |REG St.1|6754|21.03.2015|16.09.2015|
|3   ||Ex3    |REG St.1|1114|Ex3     |BLA Rd.5|0897|08.06.2015|06.08.2015|
|4   ||Ex4    |FAR RD.9|4567|Ex4     |DDR Wy.2|0897|01.03.2015|06.12.2015|
|4   ||Ex4    |FAR RD.9|4567|Ex4     |FAR RD.9|4567|09.10.2015|26.12.2015|
```

Expected Result

```
 |cID ||company|Street  |Code|del     |Street  |Code|Date 1    |Date 2    |
 +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |1   ||Ex1    |ABC Rd.1|4025|Ex1     |ABC Rd.1|4025|13.06.2015|08.08.2015|
```

respectively cID = 1

Here´s what I tried so far, but it´s not working....

```
SELECT cID 
FROM Table1 
WHERE company= del
  AND Street = Street2 
  AND Code = Cod2 
  AND (SELECT MAX (Date 1) > (=! MAX(Date2) FROM Table1 Group by CID)
```

Edit (To make it more simple to understand):

e.g. the company with the name Ex1  (cID 1) is now located in `ABC Rd.1|4025` (actual adress - the adress before is unknown) and has 3 adresses in  system, where the orders of the company has been send to.

- The first order on adress 1 `(DEL St.1|0212)` was on `01.01.2015`,

  - the last order to this adress was on `06.03.2015`.
- The first order on adress 2 `(REF Wy.1|9875)` was on `26.02.2015`

  - and the last order to this adress was on `16.05.2015` ...

-> I want the cID´s where registration adress (actual adress of the company) is the actual and only delivery adress.

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: I´m pretty sure it´s 2012

Comment: `SELECT @@VERSION`. and what would be the expected results if there were two rows where Street2 = ABC Rd.1 for CID 1? Can you update that in the sample?

Comment: Yes - it is 2012

Comment: There´s always only one row . it´s unique

Comment: The first of your WHERE clauses is "Company = Del".  Your expected results don't meet this condition (Company is 'Ex1' and Del is 'DELExa3').

Comment: What is `registration` and What is `delivery adresses`

Comment: corrected it - of cause the name of the company (company & del) is the same

Comment: With registration adress, I mean the combination of company (column 1) Street (column 2)  and Code (column 3)

Comment: Ok then address is compare with three `AND`'s like your current query. So can you explain the Date condition a litle more.

Comment: I edited it above and explained it

Comment: You add more example about how many date and address, but you dont explain which date address you want :(

Comment: I added it now: plz take a look

Comment: You really suck at this. What mean `is the actual`. Try to explain your problem like you are talking to a [**rubber duck**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: My understanding is that we are looking for companies such that the most recent delivery was made to the current company address, and such that the most recent delivery to a different address predates the first delivery to the current company address (no overlaps). In terms of query, the oldest delivery (date1) to the current address must have occurred later than the most recent delivery (date2) to any other address.

Comment: Yes - thats correct

Answer (score 1):

Try using row number to get the latest date.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY  Street, Code, company
                                    ORDER BY Date1 DESC) as rn
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Street = Street2 
      AND Code = Cod2 
      AND company = del
) T
WHERE T.rn = 1
```

Comment: Well i still don't understand what result you want. I try to do the best with what I have

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT cID
FROM Table1
WHERE Street = Street2 
  AND Code = Cod2 
  AND Date1 > ( 
                SELECT MAX(Date2)
                FROM Table1 as delivery
                WHERE Table1.cID = delivery.cID 
                 AND (delivery.Street2 <> Street OR delivery.Cod2 <> Code)
              )
```

The subquery must itself be a correct SELECT-FROM-WHERE query, and a variable must be used to disambiguate between the outer and inner tables. The inner query selects all deliveries made to the same company but excluding the current delivery, and picks the maximal most recent date. It is then compared to the oldest date of the current delivery address.

Note that the data is not in second normal form. It may be worth, depending on the use case, splitting the table into a table with companies and a table with deliveries.

On  my side, it returns 1 as expected.

Comment: I´m not 100% sure - but I think your solution is not working... I canceled the query after 5minutes without any result...

Comment: It may need a slight adjustment depending on the database used, and there are inconsistencies in the samples with spaces on Date1 vs. Date 1 which may explain the issue. I used PostgreSQL 9.6 successfully. While each database has its own SQL dialect, the general structure of a query remains the same. In any case, I hope that the above helps you towards a solution that works for SQL Server.